# How to highlight all keywords in a piece of text?

Tags: comparison, office365

We are using a large common spammer phrase list as part of our spam filtering system. Any matches in the subject or message body of an email cause it to go straight to our Office 365 hosted quarantine.

Today, I noticed our first false positive getting sent to the hosted quarantine. I want to find out which words or phrases matched something in the phrase list so I could remove it from the list but could not find it (due to the large number of keywords and phrases we now have in the list).

Everything is currently in a notepad document. I thought of using Beyond Compare but don't see how it could work in this situation.

How can I highlight matches between the original message and the keyword/phrase list?

Comment: How are the keywords separated in the text file, commas or new lines?

Comment: I just copied and pasted straight out of the Exchange Admin Center, so they are in the following format: 'name is mr' or 'name is mrs' or 'these sum of' or 'these foundation have' or 'these foundation has' or 'from your friends at' or '1st page on google' or '#1 on google' or '1st page of google' or 'google 1st page' or 'marketing experts' or 'competition analysis' or 'at affordable rates' or 'we provides' or 'does your site rank' - I don't mind changing the formatting if necessary.

Comment: 'or' makes things more complicated. Is it possible to have each keyword on a separate line? If not, then I need to modify my answer

Comment: That looks like a great answer. I ended up sending just the first half, then just the second half of the email through our mail server and then doing the same to the half that got quarantined. Once I narrowed it down to a few sentences I spotted the problem and removed the spammy phrase that apparently comes up in regular conversation sometimes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each key phrase is on a separate line then the easiest way is to use a batch file:

```
@echo off
(for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (keywords.txt) do findstr /C:"%%i" /N /I message.txt) > result.txt
```

Save it as `filter.bat` and run form the command line. `keywords.txt` is the name of the file with the keywords, e.g.

```
spammer1
spammer2
mr. spammer3
```

and `message.txt` should contain the message in question:

```
Hi, I am spammer2. Give me money

regards,
Mr. spammer3
```

After the script is run, the matching line numbers will be output in `results.txt`:

```
1:Hi, I am spammer2. Give me money
4:Mr. spammer3
```